# Custom Build Tabletop Table

Tags: gaming, monitors, thin-mini-itx

Not sure if this is the right place to be asking this question. But since this is hardware / PC related, and not woodworking, I think it would be the best place.

I'm currently in the planning process to build a new dining table, that would be able to operate as a tabletop table, specifically card and/or pen and paper. For this, one of the ends will include a table-"wing" for the Gamemaster. In this wing I want to install two angled monitors and connect them to either a mini-pc or a custom built ITX pc. The PC itself is not the difficult part, the monitors are however.

The requirements for the monitors:

- 2x Monitors (Size 15.6" ~ 17", 16:9)
- Touch capability
- Either frame-less or panel based, for easy installation
- Should run on either mini-DP, DP or HDMI. (if anyone have other suggestions please feel free to suggest it)
- Voltage in the table would be either 230V or 24V.

Some people have suggested that I simply scavenge some old laptops or monitors. While other people suggest trying to locate some on Ebay (or similar).

I was thinking that perhaps some of the people in this stackexchange might have experience with these types of custom builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ready made available, for example [this Waveshare one](https://www.waveshare.com/15.6inch-fhd-monitor.htm).

Scavenging laptop displays requires some effort since they don't use standard connectors and you need to track down adapters which work with this specific model.